# why android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" does not playing any sounds for onClick?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have make a dialpad grid. For onClick of digits I want to play some soundeffects.

Here is my XML :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/number_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And Here is code :

```
@OnClick(R.id.cardview_1)
public void onClick(View v){
    ZoroHelper.zoroLogger("TAG","isSoundEffectsEnabled : "+v.isSoundEffectsEnabled()); // Gives me TRUE
    v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    // Some Action
}
```

Also tried,
                    view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

I have used Butterknife Library.

I find various solutions but no one Help me out. Where I am going wrong?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Check your phone settings and confirm whether the sound options are turned on.

Comment: I have checked my phone settings for sound options and They are on. Other apps plays sounds for onClick in my phone but not my app plays any sound effects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"` and `android:clickable="true"` in your component.